# How can i send Multiple Objects with performSelectorOnMainThread

Tags: iphone, ios5, selector

I have two objects one is NSData and another one is NSString. I want to send this two objects with `perfomSelectorOnMainThread`. How I can do this?

Comment: Send an array/dictionary containing both the objects.

Comment: put both in an array or in dictionary and send that array or dict to performselector's object.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper Sorry i am a new as stackoverflow ..where is your answer here..you send comment only as answer. where can i mark it

Comment: Hey you marked someone else's answer??

Comment: But you still did not marked my answer...:( you can declare your method like: -(void)myMethod:(id)sender { [sender objectAtIndex:0]; [sender objectAtIndex:1]}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using XCode 4.4 and later you can simply do:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:@[objectA,objectB] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

If you have XCode version older then 4.4 use

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:objectA, objectB, nil] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This is your selector methods:

```
-(void)myMethod:(NSArray*)array{

   ObjectA *objA = [array objectAtIndex:0];
   ObjectB *objB = [array objectAtIndex:1];

}
```

Comment: I am new as iphone development how can i receive at Selector method pls help me

Comment: Just having a very zen question here: Do you consider this bad practice? Idk it is the solution to the problem but is it the ideal solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourSelectorMethod) withObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"object1",@"object2", nil]];
```